# Parent add-on's bower dependency is not downloaded while generating child add-on's blueprint in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am using a two-level hierarchy of ember add-ons. In my parent addon's `bower.json`, I have included the URL in dependencies section. Also in blueprint's `index.js`, I have used the `addBowerPackageToProject` inside `afterInstall` hook. That bower dependency is not downloaded while generating blueprints of child addon. I have also tried invoking `this._super()` in the afterInstall hook of child addon's blueprints.

Comment: `afterInstall: function() {
    return this.addBowerPackageToProject('font-awesome', '~4.2.0');
  }`
This works for me, but writing the url of a bower addon didn't work.

Comment: Did you mean in child add-on or in parent add-on @ykaragol

Comment: For parent addon. Maybe it was our mistake, but it didn't worked.

Comment: If I install parent addon separately, specified package is downloaded in bower_components folder of consuming application. But when I install and generate the blueprint of child addon, it is not downloaded.

Comment: Did anyone have any idea of how to make it work?